# VisualForce page and Page layout together for one page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, console

I have a VisualForce page for "New Case" and should use it only for special Profiles. On the another hand, I have Standard Page Layout for "New Case" for other Profiles.

To accomplish this, I've made my custom `Visualforce Page` as default "New Case" view (in `Buttons, Links, and Actions`). I added this `action` attribute to my  `page` tag:

```
action="{!if(OR($Profile.Name =='test', $Profile.Name =='test2'), 
    null , urlFor($Action.Case.NewCase, null, null, true))}"
```

So my test Profiles see Custom VF page, and other Profiles will see standard Page layout.

Problems starts in console...

If I disable my VF page (all go through Page Layout) then I can see these columns:

[image: Service Console Screenshot]

but if I use my VF page, then these columns disappear. But I need them, especially suggested articles...